# ADB wireless not working with PC connected via Ethernet cable

Tags: android, adb, wireless

I wanted to connect to my device wirelessly so I can install apps via ADB without cables. The problem is that I can't connect to my device.
My device is connected to my home's WiFi and PC via Ethernet cable but in the local network. Why I can't connect?

I'm doing this:

```
adb tcpip 5556
adb connect myipaddress:5556
```

but It's not working...

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your phone directly to your PC with USB cable for command
`adb tcpip 5556`.  Otherwise your device will not set the tcpip port. 
connect phone on PC with USB, then enter `adb tcpip 5556` and then you can disconnect it. after that second command `adb connect myipaddress:5556` will connect your device wirelessly.
And myipaddress must be IP of your phone device.

Comment: Did that but it says:  

unable to connect to 192.168.*.***:5555

Comment: Can you ping your phone from your PC? Check if you can ping. And ports must be same, if you set 5556 for one command it must be same for second.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
While the phone is wired, ADB over WiFi fails. Once you unplug you should be able to use ADB over WiFi.
I am in need to have the phone wired for one network while using ADB over the WiFi but not a successful scenario.